# Как создать шаблон функции с ограничением на несколько конкретных числовых типов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Чтобы можно было написать несколько функций с конвертацией из строки в число.

Comment: для разных типов будет разная реализация такой функции, поэтому напишите  
прототип вашей функции, и  определите ее для каждой специализации

Answer (score 1):

Вариант первый - `enable_if`, что-то типа

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>>
```

или

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value || 
                                                 std::is_same<T,char>::value>>
```

Вариант второй - `static_assert` с такого же рода проверками:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<T,int>::value,"T is'nt int");
```